# How to display a unicode character as a value in a v-select input using Vue.js

Tags: unicode, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Trying to display the unicode character "&#181" and "mL" as options for my select options.
I am using Vuetify. Not even sure if this is possible but never hurts to ask.
Need the unicode characters to show as symbols.

The symbols array i am using for the select options

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            symbols: ["&#181", "mL"]
        }
    }
}



    <v-col cols="1" md="1" class="pr-1">
      <v-text-field
        outlined
        name="processing-range-from"
        id="processing-range-from"
        type="number"
        label="From"
        min="0"
        step="10"
        v-model="product.processingRange.from"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2" md="2" class="pl-0">
      <v-select
        outlined
        attach
        label="metric"
        placeholder="metric"
        v-model="product.processingRange.fromSymbol"
        :items="symbols"
      ></v-select>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="1" md="1" class="pr-1">
      <v-text-field
        outlined
        name="processing-range-to"
        id="processing-range-to"
        type="number"
        label="To"
        min="0"
        step="10"
        v-model="product.processingRange.from"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2" md="2" class="pl-0">
      <v-select
        outlined
        attach
        label="metric"
        placeholder="metric"
        v-model="product.processingRange.toSymbol"
        :items="symbols"
      ></v-select>
    </v-col>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the unicode character directly, not its code.

`symbols: ["µ", "mL"]`

Comment: Wow, can't believe that never crossed my mind. Thank you so much for your wisdom!